# Excel VBA - File won't close after Workbook_BeforeClose()

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.EnableEvents = True
Close_Spreadsheet = True
frmAccess.Show
If Close_Spreadsheet = True Then
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End If
...
...
End Sub
```

When I open the file, the frmAccess form is displayed, which is used to sign into the file.  If I close the form without signing in, the variable Close_Spreadsheet remains true.  The if statement is entered and the Close command is called and control switches to Workbook_BeforeClose.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

After the Workbook_BeforeClose sub, control goes back to the line after the Close call and continues as if it wasn't there.  In other words, the file DOES NOT CLOSE.

If I step through the Workbook_Open sub, it works perfectly.  The file closes after completing the last line in Workbook_BeforeClose.  I commented out all the other code to make sure that nothing else was affecting this.  What is going on?

Comment: What code is in `Workbook_BeforeClose` ?

Comment: I found the problem (sort of).  I've been opening the xlsm file by clicking on the Open Folder icon and clicking the file in the Recent Files history list.  Every time I did this, I got this strange behavior.  But If I went directly to the folder where the file is stored and opened it by double-clicking on the file name, it works perfectly.  I repeated this a few times to confirm it.  Thank you Microsoft.

Comment: @TimWilliams  I commented out everything in the Workbook_BeforeClose sub, except what you see above and I still got the same behavior.  What I had in there was just a ActiveWorkbook.Save  command.